# I'm tracking clickbacks of a link on my site and when I share on twitter I'm getting too many clicks

Tags: http, twitter, http-request

On our website we've launched a feature where people can track how many clicks they get on a link they share on twitter.

The problem is that when I share the link on Twitter, I immediately get 5 clicks. Is there any way to prevent this from happening? (i.e. is there a specific api I can use to prevent repetitive requests from a website).

Comment: what you mean by repetitive requests from a website??

Comment: I think what he wants to say is that as soon as the link (url to his website) is shared on twitter, 5 requests are made to that link (which he is perhaps, tracking) even though no one physically clicks on the link.

Comment: @TJ- Than it is more of less thing how Twitter handling the sharing and more debugging needs to check why 5 requests :)

Answer (score 0):

Once a tweet is posted, there are few bots which go through the content of the tweet and crawl to the link . I guess when the bot hits your url u can check the header info like web-client etc to authenticate it . Hope that helps .